# What happens if a seat belt is found broken, before flight take off?

Tags: faa-regulations, safety, passenger, seats

What happens in a commercial airliner, when a passenger finds the seat belt to be broken. Does the crew de-plane the passenger or do they provide him something like a child/infant seat belt?

I'm also curious as to FAA's regulation on this area, if any.

Comment: The infant seat belt is attached to the actual seat belt, so not an option (besides being way too small). Regulatory the seat belt needs to be there, so I assume if there is no other free seat the passanger will be either removed from the plane or one of the pilots takes them on their lap.

Comment: What about the seat belts used by crew during safety demonstration?

Comment: @Firee If you look closely, you will see that all of the equipment used in the safety demo is marked "for demonstration only" or similar since it is not maintained.

Comment: F/A jumpseats might be usable in some jurisdictions I think.

Comment: The seatbelt is either replaced with a spare or the seat is "deferred" (put out of service) until it can be repaired.

Comment: This happened to me once. The crew relocated me to another seat. You cannot fly without the basic security gear.

Comment: And a corollary question: What happens if a seatbelt on a full aircraft becomes inoperable during flight?

Comment: Sounds like the best thing to do (if in a hurry) would be to report it after takeoff. Do seatbelts on aircraft save lives anyway?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Options would be to either move the passenger to another seat & placard that seat as unusable, or go back to the gate and have maintenance fix what's broken. In the former case, the seat would most likely be fixed by a mechanic at the next station.

The seatbelts used in the F/A demos are seatbelt *extensions*, which still need the installed seatbelt itself to be intact. They are fully functional as such, though, unlike the demo life vests & O2 masks, which indeed are "demo only" and of no use at all in a real emergency.

For a mechanic, the seatbelt is quick & easy to replace, although without needle-nose pliers (and a spare male or female belt), rather difficult for the crew -- who wouldn't be allowed to anyway.

The FAA requires that every passenger has a seatbelt and has been told how & when to use it, and that the crew has verified that they have it on before takeoff.

Comment: Also, the crew would have a hard time doing the required maintenance paperwork, including returning it to service...